# How would I determine the rate that a field value shows up, when it shows up at all in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a huge data set.  Each record has a timestamp on it (in string format).  I'm trying to determine how many times a particular field is a particular value.  In a more concrete fashion:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| TimeStamp           | Value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | A     | A shows up 3 times in the first hour
| 2022-01-01 00:00:01 | B     |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:05 | A     |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:09 | A     |
| 2022-01-01 05:00:01 | A     | A shows up 2 times in the sixth hour
| 2022-01-01 05:00:02 | A     |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I'd like to see how many times in an hour that `A` shows up on average hourly excluding the time that it doesn't show up at all.  In this case 5/2 => 2.5 times per hour.  Is this even possible with SQL or will I have to write an external script to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT AVG(counter) average
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) counter
  FROM tablename
  WHERE Value = 'A'
  GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', TimeStamp)
);
```

or, with `AVG()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER () average
FROM tablename
WHERE Value = 'A'
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', TimeStamp);
```

If you want results for all `Value`s:

```
SELECT Value, AVG(counter) average
FROM (
  SELECT Value, COUNT(*) counter
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY Value, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', TimeStamp)
)
GROUP BY Value;
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Value, 
       AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY Value) average
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Value, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', TimeStamp);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5d0e733f8757bc0d38236778df75ca92).